# Ocultar y Mostrar con animación la ActionBar en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Para mostrar o ocultar la `ActionBar` uso el siguiente código:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {

    getSupportActionBar().setShowHideAnimationEnabled(true);

    if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }

}
```

Pero por mucho que asigne con `setShowHideAnimationEnabled` al ocultarse o mostrarse continua hacerlo de golpe.

¿Cómo se puede asignar una animación para que se muestre o oculte, la toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo acabo de encontrar, para que se aplique una animación al mostrar o ocultar la `ActionBar` en componente padre de la `toolbar` en este caso es la `AppBarLayout` se inserta la propiedad `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

Quedando así:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"

        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Y el código java se puede quitar el .setShowHideAnimationEnabled:

```
if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {

    if (getSupportActionBar().isShowing()) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
    }
}
```